# Find MFC class memory layout automatically in IDA?

Tags: ida, mfc

#### Background

I was using IDA to reverse engineer an DLL which uses MFC100.

I was reading [Reversing an MFC application: How to find class memory layouts?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12385/reversing-an-mfc-application-how-to-find-class-memory-layouts) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126694/idapro-loading-c-header-files-into-idapro-for-structures , where two answers suggest going to the correct header file and copy&paste the struct defintion (which is hard, because C++ has templates and vftable. Also, nested classes...), and one answer suggests making a test program and use IDA to decompile it to get the struct declaration, which is not possible because programs don't (appear to) store struct declaration. (see below)

---

Consider a small example. (with `CStdioFile` and some MFC thing)

```
#include <afxwin.h>

class HelloApplication : public CWinApp
{
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
};

HelloApplication HelloApp;

class HelloWindow : public CFrameWnd
{       
    CButton* m_pHelloButton;
public: 
    HelloWindow();
};


BOOL HelloApplication::InitInstance()
{       
    m_pMainWnd = new HelloWindow(); 
    m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow); 
    m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow(); 
    return TRUE;
}


HelloWindow::HelloWindow()
{       
    Create(NULL,            
        "Hello World!",         
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_HSCROLL,             
        CRect(0,0,140,80));     
    m_pHelloButton = new CButton();
    m_pHelloButton->Create("Hello World!",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,CRect(20,20,120,40),this,1);

    // some code for file reading
    CStdioFile Inputfile, Outputfile;
    CFileException FileExc;
    UINT nOpenFlags;
    CString s;
    nOpenFlags = CFile::modeRead;
    if (!Inputfile.Open("Console.txt", nOpenFlags, &FileExc)) {
        FileExc.ReportError();
        return;
    }
    nOpenFlags = CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeCreate;
    if (!Outputfile.Open("Output.txt", nOpenFlags, &FileExc)) {
        FileExc.ReportError();
        return;
    }
    while (Inputfile.ReadString(s))
        Outputfile.WriteString(s+'\n');
    Inputfile.Close();
    Outputfile.Close();

}
```

Command line used (assuming the file above is named `a.cpp`):

```
cl.exe a.cpp /EHsc /link /debug /subsystem:windows
```

Here, I intentionally use `/debug` to make reverse engineering easier.

When IDA ask me if I want to load the PDB file, I chose "Yes".

However:

When loading the executable with IDA, neither the "Local Types" window nor the "Structures" window shows anything about `CFile`. Therefore, the functions which use them, use offsets to refer to the members.

[image: Pseudocode of CFile::CFile]

<sub>In this particular case I use `CFile`, but I assume it's similar for other classes.</sub>

I know I can go to the header file in `atlmfc\` to read the class definition and work out the member names, but that's too tedious and IDA may have it built-in already. So:

---

#### The question

Is there any way to quickly give IDA the definition of `CFile`?

Comment: If you compile your windows program with debug information and importing the resulting debug info .pdb file with the corresponding menu command ( https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/430.shtml ) you'll probably be able to see the CFIle definition.

Comment: @ws Won't loading the file import the PDB automatically?

Comment: IDA will usually ask if you want to load the PDB.

Comment: It still doesn't work. (post updated...)

Comment: Is it IDA free by any chance ? Is it possible that you are running IDA on Linux ?

Comment: @ws You mean, it should just work, and it's weird that it doesn't work for me?

Comment: Looking at [other posts](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16486/stl-map-and-map-entry-structures-for-ida-hexrays), it looks like that there is no automatic way to get the C++ structures in IDA.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is: `/Zi` is required. Including just `/debug` is not enough. That's because the type information is stored in the compiler `.pdb` file. See also [Compiler PDB file and the Linker PDB file - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796090/compiler-pdb-file-and-the-linker-pdb-file).

The command line can looks like this:

```
cl.exe /Zi a.cpp /EHsc /link /subsystem:windows
```

Note that `/Zi` implies `/debug` (therefore it's not necessary to specify `/debug` when `/Zi` is included)

**Hint**: It's not necessary to build the executable. Just compile the file itself is enough (using `/c`).

---

There are some other problems that one may get while doing that:

1. The error message

   ```
   << It appears that MS DIA SDK is not installed.
   Please try installing "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package / x86" >>
   ```

   appears in the "Output window".

   Solution: just install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29).
2. ```
   Internal IDA Error

   Oops! internal error 984 occured.
   Further work is not possible and IDA will close.
   ```

   It's [a bug that is fixed in IDA 6.9](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/6.9/index.shtml).
3. The classes just don't appear in "Local Types" tab.

   Check the output window to see if the error message mentioned in problem 1 appears.

---

By the way, it is possible to import any C++ type into IDA using this method, not just specifically MFC.